# How to create a countdown timer in a Java Applet?

Tags: java, timer, applet

I'm working on a final project for school with a Java applet that counts down from a given interval to zero. When a Rectangle on screen experiences a mouse down event, it is supposed to execute the timer; however this does not occur; the program ends up crashing. I've seen a lot of examples of timers online, but many are using Java's built in timer class, which I am not using. I figured there must be a more basic way to do a simple timer. All variables have been declared at the top of the class.

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
    {
    if(start.inside(x,y))
    {
        timerAct = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        endTime = startTime + interval;

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 < endTime) {
            while (startTime != System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) {
                startTime += 1;
                timeLeft = (endTime - startTime);
            }
        }
        timerAct = false;
    }
    repaint();
    return true;
}
```

The logic seems to workout okay because this began as System.out.println(), and it worked just fine.   Then, it was converted to store the variable timeLeft. In the paint method, I have

```
    g.drawString("Time: " + timeLeft, 420, 180);
```

to print the the time remaining. I also have the update method; but it doesn't seem to make a difference. And I know the issue isn't because I'm changing a variable. My mouse down method has an if statement with a different rectangle that tracks clicks (not shown), and it updates a counter of clicks on screen in the applet window without any issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The mouseDown method is depreciated.  Where is the interval field coming from?  Your double while loop is maxing the CPU and probably blocking the GUI.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Unfortunately, it was a teacher requirement as the final project. I tried commenting out the second while loop, but it still crashed. The interval is coming from a class variable that correlates to the level. It's a given time period; for example 60 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/concurrency/online/java/tsld005.htm). It's pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would code a simple countdown timer.  This code needs to be run in a separate thread and not the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

```
private void countdownTimer(int intervalSecs) {
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (intervalSecs * 1000L);
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
        sleep();
        repaint();
    }
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void repaint() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where would I add this? You say it needs to run as a separate thread, but I'm unsure on how to do this.

Comment: Alright I have this working; I added a System.out.println after current time in the while loop to determine if it was indeed working. Well it is; However, this has caused a new issue. My mouse down method has another if statement in it that increments every time the mouse is clicked. That in turn updates a variable that is being displayed on the window. But this does not update when the timer is running. How do I get this vital component to function correctly?